# Posting data to web service from Android doesn't get sent

Tags: android, c++, rest, sockets, post

I am working on a project which was working fine before Christmas but suddenly doesn't without any changes being made.

The project involves a C++ which listens on a particular port and listens to post requests in a REST API to process the data and store in a database.

It consists of an Android library which gathers information and then sends this as an HTTP POST to the rest API on the C++ app.

The C++ app prints out the HTTP response that was received straight from receiving it on the socket before any processing done. First the android app has to send an initalisation request to the C++ app, the C++ prints the request and shows post data was sent, and successfully initalises and sends a response back to android including a session cookie. I then re-use the HttpClient within Android to post the next request which contains a fair amount of data but this request doesn't work.

When stepping through the android library I can see the post values have been successfully set and are being used to perform the HTTP request, however, the C++ app only receives the HTTP headers, not any post data.

If in the second request, I replace the post data with only a couple of post fields, the C++ then sees the post data, so it looks like the DefaultHTTPClient in Android isn't sending the post data if the post data is quite large.

Below is how I am posting the data in Android

```
if (httpClient == null)
            {
                //AndroidHttpClient client = new AndroidHttpClient();
                httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            }
            HttpParams httpParams = httpClient.getParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 3000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 3000);
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(serverURL);
            //httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            httpPost.setHeader("Authorisation-Token", authorisationToken);
            httpPost.setHeader("Connection", "close");
            //httpPost.setHeader("Cookie", "SESSIONID=zd8d5n3kucysl4idug1911m7ye");
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postData, "UTF-8"));

            String headers = "";

            responseHandler = new ResponseHandler<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public String handleResponse(HttpResponse httpResponse) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
                {
                    return EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
                }
            };
            responseBody = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);

            Log.d("Response", responseBody);
            //httpClient = null;
            if (responseBody != null && !responseBody.isEmpty())
            {
                httpClient.getConnectionManager().closeIdleConnections(0, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);
                return jsonObject;
            }
            else
            {
                httpClient.getConnectionManager().closeIdleConnections(0, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
                return null;
            }
```

As an example the post data is being created as follows:

```
postData = new ArrayList<>();
            postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Test", "Item 1"));
            postData.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Test 2", "Item 2"));
```

and the above is passed in to the execute command of the ASyncTask.

Below is how I am receiving the data on the socket from C++

```
string LinuxSocket::receiveDataOnSocket(int *socket)
{
    string receiveData = "";
    char * temp = NULL;
    int bytesReceived = 0;
    do
    {
        bytesReceived = recv(*socket, this->buffer, this->bufferLength, 0);
        if (bytesReceived < 0)
        {
            stringstream logstream;
            logstream << "Failed to read data on socket. Error: " << strerror(bytesReceived);
            this->bitsLibrary->writeToLog(logstream.str(), "LinuxSocket", "receiveDataOnSocket");
            this->closeSocket(socket);
            throw SocketException(strerror(bytesReceived));
        }
        //If we got here then we should be able to get some data
        temp = new char[bytesReceived + 1];
        strncpy(temp, this->buffer, bytesReceived);
        temp[bytesReceived] = '\0';
        receiveData.append(temp);
        delete[] temp;
        temp = NULL;
        memset(this->buffer, 0, this->bufferLength);
    } while (bytesReceived == this->bufferLength);

    return receiveData;
}
```

The post data that I am sending is a follows:

```
POST /crash HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: My Android User Agent
Authorisation-Token: DlzSIkx4ro*OatHCV6epfWY0F
Connection: close
Content-Length: 1231
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: 192.168.1.123:500
Cookie: SESSIONID=6rc5q1db0z8lupe5uij5ten3mw
Cookie2: $Version=1

Severity=Critical&DeviceID=36e85611db16c7fa&VersionName=1.5&DeviceType=Android&ROMBuild=sdk_gphone_x86-userdebug+8.0.0+OSR1.170901.056+4497355+dev-keys&KernelVersion=3.18.81%2B&DeviceBrand=google&DeviceModel=Android+SDK+built+for+x86&APILevel=26&ScreenResolution=1080+x+1776&Locale=English&MobileNetwork=Android&CrashType=Handled&ExceptionType=java.lang.Exception&Stacktrace=java.lang.Exception%3A+Standard+Exception+been+thrown%0A%09at+com.MyCompany.MyApp.MainActivity%242.onClick%28MainActivity.java%3A67%29%0A%09at+android.view.View.performClick%28View.java%3A6256%29%0A%09at+android.view.View%24PerformClick.run%28View.java%3A24701%29%0A%09at+android.os.Handler.handleCallback%28Handler.java%3A789%29%0A%09at+android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage%28Handler.java%3A98%29%0A%09at+android.os.Looper.loop%28Looper.java%3A164%29%0A%09at+android.app.ActivityThread.main%28ActivityThread.java%3A6541%29%0A%09at+java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke%28Native+Method%29%0A%09at+com.android.internal.os.Zygote%24MethodAndArgsCaller.run%28Zygote.java%3A240%29%0A%09at+com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main%28ZygoteInit.java%3A767%29%0A&CustomProperty=%7B%22Test+Non+Json+Property%22%3A%22Here+is+my+value%22%7D&AppID=15869700
```

As an example the post data that successfully works is a follows:

```
POST /initialise HTTP/1.1
Authorisation-Token: DlzSIkx4ro*OatHCV6epfWY0F
Connection: close
Content-Length: 48
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: 192.168.1.123:500
User-Agent: My Android User Agent

ApplicationID=15869700&DeviceID=36e85611db16c7fa
```

I've also captured the request from Android and sent it from a Rest API Test Client [Insomnia.Rest](https://insomnia.rest/) and sent this to the Rest API and the C++ successfully sees all of the post data, so it looks like the problem is the Android library won't send post data if its of a certain size.

Is this the case, and how can I get round this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue with this, there were two separate things that I've done to resolve this.

The issue with no post data at all being sent, I changed from the org.apache.DefaultHTTPClient to the OkHTTPClient. From looking at Google it looks like the apache version has been deprecated and the OkHTTPClient is the preferred HTTP client anyway. This then sent some post data but not everything. This brings me to the second fix (I don't think the issue was actually with the apache client, I think it was my C++ receiving data on the socket).

The second fix I did was to change my receiveDataOnSocket function in the C++ app.

When I've worked on socket to socket communication then normally if the buffer is full, then usually I can expect to receive more data, if the buffer is only partly full, then all data is sent and I return the received data.

It looks like HTTP doesn't necessarily send as much as the buffer on receiving socket can handle, I've therefore changed my receive data on socket to process the data as its being received to look for the Content-Length header, and the length of the body that I may have, then on each subsequent `recv` call, I increment the current body count by the receivedBytes count and if the body length is equal to the content length I stop receiving data on the socket and return the HTTP request.